# How to execute a query using hibernatetemplate in spring mvc without using xml. my code is here

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@Repository
public class JobSheetDaoImpl implements JobSheetDao {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    
    @Transactional
    public void createJobSheet(JobSheet jobSheet) {
        
        
        //to get technician who have minimum workload
        
        String query="select * from Technician Where expertiseCompany=? "
                + "AND expertiseDevice=? AND totalJobs=(select MIN(totalJobs) "
                + "from Technician)";
        
            //how to fire this query using hibernatetemplate ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Hibernate Session like this:

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = hibernateTemplate.getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
sqlQuery.setParamer(...) // set the parameters you need
List result = sqlQuery.list();
```